# How to add SwiftUI sortable header

Tags: ios, swiftui

- Which is the best way to create a list with sortable headers
- How to apply .listRowBackground to a GridRow if it is within a List?
- The headers should be aligned with the respective column

Let's consider this list

| A Filter button |  | Price | Average | AnotherDouble |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A String | Spacer() | 10 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

Price, Average, and AnotherDouble should be aligned to the right

```
List {
    Grid {
        quotationHeader
            .gridCellUnsizedAxes([.horizontal, .vertical])


    Divider()
        .gridCellUnsizedAxes([.horizontal, .vertical])

    ForEach(stats) { stat in
        QuotationGridRow(quotation: stat)
        if stat != stats.last {
            Divider()
               .gridCellUnsizedAxes([.horizontal, .vertical])
        }
    }
    .listRowSeparator(.visible)
}
// ...

private var quotationHeader: some View {
    GridRow { 
        // A FILTER BUTTON
        if (sortable) {
            QuotationOrderByHeaders(viewModel: orderByViewModel)
        } else {
            QuotationWithoutOrderByHeaders(viewModel: orderByViewModel)
        }
    }
}
// ... QuotationGridRow
struct QuotationGridRow: View {
    var quotation: PlayerQuotation
    var body: some View {
        GridRow() {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(quotation.surname)
                Text(String(quotation.teamId))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            .gridColumnAlignment(.leading)
            Text(String(quotation.price))
            Text("\(quotation.statistics.fantaAverage, specifier: "%.2f")")
            Text("\(quotation.statistics.voteAverage, specifier: "%.2f")")
    }
}
```

​

Comment: you might want to use `Table`

Comment: The table will only show one column on iPhone (compact mode)